# AttributeError: type object 'Article' has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот мой models.py

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
class Article( models.Model):
    article_title=models.CharField('название статьи', max_length=200)
    article_text=models.TextField('текст статьи')
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField('дата публикации')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article_title

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >=(timezone.now()- datetime.timedelta(days =7))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Статья'
        verbose_name_plural='Статьи'

class Comment(models.Model):
    article=models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    author_name= models.CharField('имя автора',max_length= 50)
    comment_text= models.CharField('текст комментария',max_length= 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Комементарий'
        verbose_name_plural='Комментарии'
```

вот views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Article,Comment

def index(request):
    latest_articles_list=Article.object.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    return render(request, 'articles/list.html', {'latest_articles_list':latest_articles_list})
```

Помогите, что делать с ошибкой

Answer (score 1):

Я просто тупой. Я допустил опечатку надо было писать не object  а objects.ಠ_ಠ